# Отменить замутнение при применении свойства disable JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Когда применяешь свойство disable на любом элементе сцены, чтобы он был не активен, элемент замутняется и не очень видно, что, например, написано в TextArea. Можно как-нибудь убрать это замутнение или отменить?

Answer (score 3):

Да можно. Переопредел в css файле для этого элемента свойство [`disabled`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#node).

Answer (score 2):

Вот такой css применил на всю панель с элементами:

```
   .label:disabled,
    .button:disabled,
    .toggle-button:disabled,
    .radio-button:disabled,
    .check-box:disabled,
    .hyperlink:disabled,
    .menu-button:disabled,
    .split-menu-button:disabled,
    .slider:disabled,
    .scroll-bar:disabled,
    .scroll-pane:disabled,
    .progress-bar:disabled,
    .progress-indicator:disabled,
    .text-input:disabled,
    .choice-box:disabled,
    .combo-box-base:disabled,
    .date-cell:disabled > *,
    .list-view:disabled,
    .tree-view:disabled,
    .table-view:disabled,
    .tree-table-view:disabled,
    .tab-pane:disabled,
    .titled-pane:disabled > .title,
    .accordion:disabled > .titled-pane > .title,
    .tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:disabled,
    .menu:disabled,
    .menu-item:disabled > .label,
    .menu-item:disabled,
    .list-cell:filled:selected:focused:disabled,
    .list-cell:filled:selected:disabled,
    .tree-cell:filled:selected:focused:disabled,
    .tree-cell:filled:selected:disabled,
    .tree-cell > .tree-disclosure-node:disabled,
    .tree-table-row-cell > .tree-disclosure-node:disabled,
    .table-row-cell:selected:disabled,
    .tree-table-row-cell:selected:disabled,
    .table-cell:selected:disabled,
    .tree-table-cell:selected:disabled,
    .spinner:disabled {
        -fx-opacity: 1.0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Предложу обходной путь.

В `TextArea` (как и во многих других) нужно вместо `.disable()` выставить `.setEditable(false)`. Про кнопки не скажу, а вот `Label` можно заменить на `Text` (его вышестоящее окно не затеняет)